# How to reset password for Azure AD account

Tags: powershell, azure

I am trying to reset password of one Azure AD account by Set-AzureRMADUser cmdlets, but it throwing error "Set-AzureRmADUser : Property passwordProfile.password is invalid." COuld you please check?
Below is the code.

```
Set-AzureRmADUser -UserPrincipalName XXXX -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString -String "XXXXX" -Force –AsPlainText)
```

Below is the complete error.

```
Set-AzureRmADUser : Property passwordProfile.password is invalid.
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-AzureRmADUser -UserPrincipalName admin@mit1openlinkcloud.onmicros        ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Update-AzureRmADUser], Exception
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ActiveDirectory.UpdateAzureADUserCommand
```

Comment: Any update this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You could try the command below.

```
Set-AzureADUserPassword -ObjectId <ObjectId> -Password <Password>
```

Refer to the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/set-azureaduserpassword?view=azureadps-2.0).

**Update**:

It may caused by your `SecureString` format, the password must meet the tenant's password complexity requirements. Refer to [Password policy in Azure AD](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj943764.aspx). You could refer to my specific command, it works fine.

```
$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "P@ssW0rD!" -Force –AsPlainText
Set-AzureADUserPassword -ObjectId "ce336193xxxxxxxx" -Password $Password
```

[image]

Try to login to azure portal use the new password, it works fine.

[image]

Besides, I suppose the error of your command that you post may caused by it too, you could check it.

Comment: I got the below error.



$password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "XX" -Force –AsPlainText
Set-AzureADUserPassword -ObjectId "XX" -Password $Password



Set-AzureADUserPassword : Error occurred while executing SetUser
Code: Request_BadRequest
Message: Property passwordProfile.password is invalid.
RequestId: cc89fdf2-36a8-422c-949c-cc580624f29a
DateTimeStamp: Wed, 11 Jul 2018 09:44:12 GMT
Details: PropertyName  - passwordProfile.password, PropertyErrorCode  - InvalidLength
HttpStatusCode: BadRequest
HttpStatusDescription: Bad Request
HttpResponseStatus: Completed

Comment: @SumanGhosh According the error message `passwordProfile.password, PropertyErrorCode - InvalidLength`, I supposed your password does not meet the tenant's password complexity requirements, I think you could check it with the link I mentioned in my reply.